# Outlook Interop in .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: .net-core, outlook, interop, .net-core-3.0

I migrated our project from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.0 (C#, WPF) and now I can not use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` anymore, because it is not compatible with .NET Core 3.0. What I want to achieve is opening/sending prefilled Outlook Emails.

Is there an alternative to this interop dll, or maybe a way to use .NET Framework for only this reference?

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
- NetOffice.Outlook

Comment: If you're still deploying to a windows machine, you could have a 2nd program, maybe a service, that's running on 472 that your core program can talk to

Comment: @nitg The suggestion from user `@PAQ` is well explained and works. If it works for you also, you may want to mark his solution as an `Answer` so other can benefit from it, as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Right click Dependencies and click "Add Reference"
2. Select Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library under the COM tab.
3. Under Dependencies/COM in your project, select Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook reference, then under "Properties" set "Embed Interop Types" to "Yes"
4. I also had to uninstall the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook NuGet package because it caused a conflict with the reference in Dependencies/COM.

Outlook automation is now working fine.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen online so far for on this issue. Other suggestions/solutions including the one given in [official demo](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo) seem quite complicated and confusing. Thank you for sharing your solution. Your solution is well explained step-by-step and much more clean and straight forward. It helped me a great deal and I hope it would help other readers, as well. Good job and thank you. I've asked the `OP` (@nitg) to mark your solution as an `Answer` if it worked for him/her.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you for the answer, this worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue when trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000. It won't run when I target .net core 3.00 preview 7.

At this stage I do not think there is any other option than reverting back to .NEW Core 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while migrating components with Office interop for Excel and Outlook to .NET Core 3.0. I found out that this is only a problem of the Nuget packages Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. The packages probably need an update to work with 3.0?

If I make direct references to the Interop assemblies all is working well. Here is a [link](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo) to an example for this.

If you use Visual Studio, you need an additional workaround to achieve this. From the linked sample:

> Adding COM references to .NET Core projects from Visual Studio is not
>   currently supported. The workaround is to create a .NET Framework
>   project, add the COM references, and then copy the relevant
>   COMReference elements in the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in a roundabout way.  Here is how:

1. Create a temporary .NET framework project.
2. Add the references to COM components (Microsoft.Outlook.Interop).
3. Open that csproj file and copy the entire  those components are located in, over to your .NET Core project.

The nuget packages seem to be incompatible at the moment.

Reference: [DotNet Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo)